# Knitting Rmarkdown to Network Path in Rstudio Fails

Tags: r, pandoc, rstudio

I have Rmarkdown code that functioned without error knitting to HTML, yet after attempting to knit as a Word document, I cannot knit **any** Rmarkdown files that are saved on a network drive.  If I save the Rmarkdown file to a local drive, I have no knitting issues.

The error I get when knitting to a network drive is:

> C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS test.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output test.html --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --table-of-contents --toc-depth 3 --variable toc_float=1 --variable toc_selectors=h1,h2,h3 --variable toc_collapsed=1 --variable toc_smooth_scroll=1 --variable toc_print=1 --template "C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-35~1.1\library\RMARKD~1\rmd\h\DEFAUL~1.HTM" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable "theme:cerulean" --include-in-header "C:\Users\bcohen\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpohSxZZ\rmarkdown-str2a8871fc2471.html" --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" 
>   pandoc.exe: test.utf8.md: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
>   Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
>   Execution halted

I have used @Yihui's advice [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1209), and [here](https://yihui.name/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/), to no avail.

I have done a COMPLETE uninstall and reinstall of Rstudio, as well.  The problem persists.

sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.5.1   htmltools_0.3.6  tools_3.5.1      yaml_2.2.0               Rcpp_1.0.1       rmarkdown_1.12.5
 [7] knitr_1.22       xfun_0.6         digest_0.6.18    evaluate_0.13
```

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AColeman answered this question on Stackoverflow.

I mapped a new network drive to a new arbitrary letter and then opened my files anew via Rstudio's GUI. Once saved to the new drive letter, all worked well.

[See his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161177/r-markdown-openbinaryfile-does-not-exist-no-such-file-or-directory/55616529?noredirect=1#comment97966859_55616529) in the comments to the post.